# Copying two columns from a foreign table into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, debugging, insert

```
INSERT INTO Confirmed (TotalDeaths, Population)
SELECT TotalDeaths, Population
FROM Deaths
WHERE UID IS NOT NULL;
```

Copy the values for the columns named TotalD and Pop from the Deaths Table to the Confirmed Table (same names, both contains UID primary Key)

Failed to execute query. Error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UID', table 'dbo.Confirmed'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

I keep running into a problem where I get compiler errors due to the primary key not allowing nulls. I'm not sure where the null keys are even coming from when it shouldn't be null to begin with.

Both tables have very similar columns, but in this case all that needs to be mentioned is that there are three columns in both tables that are crucial, which are: UID int NOT NULL, TotalDeaths int NOT NULL, Population int NOT NULL.

Comment: Answer is in your question :) `UID int NOT NULL` but you are trying to insert `null` by not providing what to insert on UID column.

Comment: Based on the error message, you are using ms sql server and not mysql.

Comment: You don't tell us whether `UID` is (or should be) an identity column?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be UID is not null column. Use below query

```
INSERT INTO Confirmed (UID, TotalDeaths, Population)
SELECT UID, TotalDeaths, Population
FROM Deaths
WHERE UID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Failed to execute query. Error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'iso2', table 'cse414-20sp.dbo.Confirmed'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I tried using that statement but I still keep having errors. Lmk if you need more details

Comment: @cliffordkei so tell us what issues you are having - it won't be the same one. And also explain whether you have an identity id or not.